# Archiving data of specific table in AWS RDS periodically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I use AWS RDS as a database for my Spring boot application. I would like to archive earlier than 6 months of data from one specific table. In this context, I have gone through a few articles here but did not get any concrete idea of how to do this. Could anyone please help here?

Comment: What are the access patterns for the archived data? Should it be immediately available (i.e. within the same RDS instance)? Do you require SQL to access archived data or an intermediate _load from files_ step is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to backup with RDS itself, your options are limited.  You can, of course, use automated RDS snapshots, but that won't let you pick a specific table (it will backup the entire database) and can't be set for retention longer than 35 days.  Alternatively, you could manually initiate a snapshot, but you can't indicate a retention period.  In this case though, you could instead use the AWS published [rds-snapshot-tool](https://github.com/awslabs/rds-snapshot-tool) which will help you automate the snapshot process and let you specify a maximum age of the snapshot.  This is likely the easiest way to use RDS for your question.  If you only wanted to restore one specific table (and didn't care about have the other tables in the backup), you could restore the snapshot and just immediately DROP the tables you don't care about before you start using the snapshot.

However, if you really care about only backing up one specific table, then RDS itself is out as a possible means for taking the backups on your behalf.  I am assuming a mysql database for your spring application, in which case you will need to use the mysqldump tool to grab the database table you are interested in.  You will need to manually call that tool from an application and then store the data persistently somewhere (perhaps S3).  You will also need to manage the lifecycle on that backup, but if you do use S3, you can set a lifecycle policy to automatically age out and drop old files (backups, in this case).